# Is it possible to connect PhpStorm to remote server using pem file?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have searched for possible way to to do that. I have also read JetBrains official documentation. But I haven't found any possible way. Is the any way to do this?

Comment: In fact, PhpStorm should support .pem keys for SSH configurations.
What does not work for you exactly?

Comment: In the official documentation there is no support for .pem file. Check this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html).